# How to manually unmount volumes after recovering files in Azure?

Tags: azure, file, recovery, file-recovery, unmount

In Azure portal "File Recovery" functionality provides us a simple 3-step process:

1. Select the restore point (date)
2. Generate the password and download the script to mount the restore point drives.
3. Unmount the drives after file recovery.

We perform the steps to mount the volumes and take some time to review the backup, and at the same time we are working in azure portal and for any reason (accidentally or deliberately) we close this tab and lose the unmount button.

How to execute step 3 manually? (to unmount the volumes). This is a temporary volume mount but how can we do it any time manually?

Answer (score 1):

Start a new file recovery which will clear the existing disk mounts as part of the process.  Once it completes mounting the new one, you can click the Unmount option on the tab that you leave open this time.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is to late but, had the same issue and was able to manually unmount it by opening Task Mgr and you should see a services named the same as the exe downloaded, if you stop that services it should close the connection.
Worked for me.